# One url works, the other should, but doesn't

Tags: python, python-2.7, request

When I run my code below, with the first url nothing seems to happen, and the last print statement hit is #2

But when I run it with the second link I am able to get the document I need from the website and save it as a text file and continue with parsing it. I have a bunch of other links I cycle through with this and they all work too

```
import requests
import os
import logging

logging.basicConfig(filename='example.log', filemode='w', level=logging.NOTSET)    

#This one doesn't work
url = "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/full-index/2017/QTR3/master.idx"

#This one does work
#url = "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/full-index/2017/QTR4/master.idx"

print "1"

r = requests.get(url)
textfile = open("ugh2.txt", "w")

print "2"

textfile.write(r.text.encode("ascii", "ignore"))
textfile.close()

print "3"

textfile = open("ugh2.txt", "r")

count = 0

linkList = []

print "4"
```

I've tried all of the debugging I know how to do, not sure what the problem is.

```
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): www.sec.gov
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://www.sec.gov:443 "GET /Archives/edgar/full-index/2017/QTR3/master.idx HTTP/1.1" 200 2730517
```

Comment: I have no problems loading that URL, nor encoding it or writing out the encoded bytes.

Comment: @MartijnPieters very weird...

Comment: Why the `r.text.encode('ascii', 'ignore')` call? Why not just write out the `r.content` raw bytes? The data is ASCII safe anyway.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I have it there just in case

Comment: If it is hanging between 1 and 2, I'm going to assume you have a disk writing issue; there is no more network interaction after 2.

Comment: @MartijnPieters So changing from `r.text.encode('ascii', 'ignore')` to `r.content` actually fixed my problem

Comment: You could try separating out the encoding and writing parts, but I *highly* doubt the encoding has anything to do with this. Since this is Python 2, writing the `str` object to a text file is otherwise *just fine*.